# File Dependencies in right order

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I have a questions about dependencies. Having the following object:

```
var files = {
    "f": {"dep": ["b", "c"]},
    "g": {"dep": ["e", "f"]},
    "a": {"dep": ["c", "b"]},
    "b": {"dep": ["d", "c"]},
    "c": {"dep": []},
    "d": {"dep": ["c"]},
    "e": {"dep": ["a"]}
};
```

Need a way to create a sequence of all files(letters) in a way, that i will not messed up the dependency order of the files ( f will not come before b and c ). So my idea is to traverse it like i would do graph crawling.

```
//TODO -o :if we have e.g "a" depend on "b" and "b" depend on "a" this will lead to
//TODO -o :infinite recursion - so we should handle this scenario.

//Todo -o :It could be optimized by checking if the file is already visited.
//stores all files in dependant order
var filesInDependantOrder = [];

//loop through all files
for (var file in files)
{
    //call the drillDownDependencies to drill down to all files
    drillDownDependencies( files[file] );

    //we exit from the recursion drillDownDependencies and add the file that we have passed
    //if not exists
    if (filesInDependantOrder.indexOf( file ) < 0) {
        filesInDependantOrder.push( file );
    }
}

function drillDownDependencies( root )
{
    //loop through all dependencies of the given file
    for (var i = 0, ilen = root["dep"].length; i < ilen; i++)
    {
        //pass the dependency to check if the given
        //dependency has dependencies by its own
        drillDownDependencies( files[root["dep"][i]] );

        //we exit from the recursion if the dependency
        //don't have other dependencies
        if (filesInDependantOrder.indexOf( root["dep"][i] ) < 0)
        {
            //push the dependency that don't have
            //other dependencies if not exists
            filesInDependantOrder.push( root["dep"][i] );
        }
    }
}

console.log(filesInDependantOrder);
```

**So the question is:** Is my solution perfect? Would it fail in somehow having file, before dependency file? I've couldn't think of a scenario that will fall on its face.

--In advanced to people, who will suggest me some implementation of AMD (like require.js) - it is not suitable for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution will work provided you have no circular dependencies.

For your information this process is called [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  The wiki page includes algorithms that will efficiently perform the sort and detect circular dependencies:

```
L ← Empty list that will contain the sorted elements
S ← Set of all nodes with no incoming edges
while S is non-empty do
    remove a node n from S
    add n to tail of L
    for each node m with an edge e from n to m do
        remove edge e from the graph
        if m has no other incoming edges then
            insert m into S
if graph has edges then
    return error (graph has at least one cycle)
else 
    return L (a topologically sorted order)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess, I'm safe then with my implementation.